# how to enable bingSpellCheck in microsoft composer luis calls?

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, bot-framework-composer, azure-language-understanding

I see in the LUIS documentation, the Bing spell check capability is no longer available in the V3 LUIS API. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-bing-spellcheck)

But then how it is works now in composer, I mean how can I use spell check capability in [bot framework composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer) now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-bing-spellcheck

The first line says "The V3 prediction API now supports the Bing Spellcheck API."
So it does support it.

In Composer you can use a direct call to the API with a Send HTTP action. see the following:

[image]